# Find profiles which have editable access to object fields

Tags: profile, fields

I often need to find out which profiles have editable access to specific fields. I do it manually by checking profile > object settings > object > fields. Is there a better way to do this.

Comment: are there any app exchange packages or chrome extensions which provide such functionality with a UI ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the FieldPermissions Object query like below as an example

```
SELECT Id, Field, ParentId, Parent.Name, Parent.Profile.Name, 
      Parent.ProfileId, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit FROM FieldPermissions 
      Where Field = 'Account.Website' AND (PermissionsEdit = true OR 
      PermissionsRead = true)
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_permissionset.htm

Use the field/filter on `Parent.IsCustom` to determine

> If true, the permission set is custom (created by an admin); if false,
>   the permission set is standard and related to a specific permsision
>   set license

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_fieldpermissions.htm

> Represents the enabled field permissions for the parent PermissionSet.
>   This object is available in API version 24.0 and later.

Comment: Do you know about any app exchange packages or chrome extensions which provide such functionality with a UI ?

Comment: If that what you wanted why did you not put that in your question?